# JS Script called by 1 element, not called by 3 others

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have a JS function which I want to call when a date or time input is changed.
With the following element, the function is called. I determine this on the basis of the fact that when I run the page in chrome with the devtools debugger open, I stop at a breakpoint at the beginning of the function. These elements are defined on a asp.net webform page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#airPickupdateInput').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
      GetTZ(selected, $('#airPickuptimeInput').val());
    }
  });
});
</script>
<input id="airPickupdateInput" class="timepicker datepicker" placeholder="Pickup Date" type="text" runat="server" />
<input type="text" id="airPickuptimeInput" class="timepicker" placeholder="Pickup Time" runat="server" onchange="GetTZ($('airPickupdateInput').val(), this.val())" />
```

When I choose a date from the datepicker element named airPickupdateInput the function is called as expected.  However, when I change the value in the input text box airPickupTimeInput the function is not called.

Furthermore, in a separate area of the same form, I have another pair of date/time inputs, defined as follows:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $("#gndPickupdateInput").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
              GetTZ(selected, $('#gndPickupdateInput').val());
          });
        });
      </script>
      <input id="gndPickupdateInput" class="timepicker datepicker" placeholder="Pickup Date" type="text" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="gndPickupTimeInput" class="timepicker" type="text" placeholder="Pickup Time" runat="server" onchange="GetTZ($('gndPickupdateInput').val(), this.val())" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

In this case, neither the date input nor the time input call the function on change. Furthermore, the datepicker widget is not activated.  The only difference I can see is that second group of input elements is held in a table. Is there any reason that should make a difference?

**Clarification**

I attached the datepicker to two different elements, one with id =gndPickupdateInput, and one with id=airPickupdateInput.  I expect the timepicker elements to trigger the function because of the "onchange" value.

In short, I have 3 questions:

1. Why is the function not called by either of the timepicker elements?
2. Why is the function called in the first datepicker case, but not the second?
3. Why is the datepicker widget not activated in the second case?

Answer (score 1):

**ID of an element must be unique**, So if you want to group multiple elements together with a selector use another attribute like the class.

In your case I think all the datepicker inputs has the class `datepicker` so use that class to select all datepicker input elements.

```
$(function () {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
      GetTZ(selected, $('#airPickuptimeInput').val());
    }
  });
});
```

then

```
<input class="timepicker datepicker" placeholder="Pickup Date" type="text" runat="server" />
```

When you use an id selector, it fetches only the first element with the given id that is why in your case the first element got the datepicker, not the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**ID in HTML must be unique.**

You can specify a common class then you can use [Class Selector `(".class")`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

As you already have added a common class(timepicker) use it. I would recommend you to use:

```
  $('.timepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
      GetTZ(selected, $('#airPickuptimeInput').val());
    }
  });
```